# How to arrange categorical bubble plot in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

For now, I am just trying to arrange this plot so the bubbles are descending by size but I'm stuck. This is what I have so far.

TRYING TO dput but I can't post as I keep getting notice that there is too much code - EDIT

```
 test2 <- test1 %>%
        arrange(desc(Mean_Abundance))
  
  p <- ggplot(test2, aes(x=Group , y=Legend_Taxa, size = Mean_Abundance)) +
    geom_point(alpha=0.5) +
    scale_size(range = c(.1, 24), name="TEST")
```

[image: Bubbleplot]

Simplified:

```
test2 <- test1 %>%
        arrange(desc(Mean_Abundance))
    
p <- ggplot(test2, aes(x=Group , y=Legend_Taxa, size = Mean_Abundance)) +
        geom_point(alpha=0.5) +
        scale_size(range = c(.1, 24), name="TEST")
 

dput(test2)
    structure(list(Group = structure(c(2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    4L, 1L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Control_After_Chronic Stress", "Control_Before_Chronic Stress", 
    "PNS_After_Chronic Stress", "PNS_Before_Chronic Stress"), class = "factor"), 
        Legend_Taxa = c("Lachnospiraceae", "Lachnospiraceae", "Lachnospiraceae", 
        "Lachnospiraceae", "Bacteroidaceae", "Prevotellaceae", "Prevotellaceae", 
        "Prevotellaceae", "Prevotellaceae", "Bacteroidaceae", "Bacteroidaceae"
        ), OTU = c("Otu00001", "Otu00001", "Otu00001", "Otu00001", 
        "Otu00027", "Otu00005", "Otu00005", "Otu00005", "Otu00005", 
        "Otu00027", "Otu00027"), Mean_Abundance = c(0.405092693842007, 
        0.359048433477872, 0.332269931284697, 0.277696665380067, 
        0.170291585729601, 0.0919430693649032, 0.0720937328370049, 
        0.0634804822090542, 0.0279728305028979, 0.0225672247590056, 
        0.0202216324834878), Sum_Abundnace = c(2.43055616305204, 
        2.15429060086723, 1.99361958770818, 1.6661799922804, 0.170291585729601, 
        0.27582920809471, 0.0720937328370049, 0.126960964418108, 
        0.111891322011592, 0.0225672247590056, 0.0202216324834878
        )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

[image: Simplified]

Comment: For posting your data as a dput() you could try with posting only a subset. For the reordering. Simply rearranging will have no effect on how the categories are arranged. Instead you have to convert to a factor with the order of the levels set in your desired order. To this end `forcats::fct_inorder` might be useful to set order after rearranging your data.

Comment: Try including just two from `Legend_Taxa` and 2-3 from `Group`, filtering your data for that should allow a much smaller dataset for `dput` and still provide some ability to plot and show distinction.

Comment: In what why do you want to arrange it? By both axis or one?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with `y=reorder(Legend_Taxa,Mean_Abundance)`

```
p <- ggplot(test1, aes(x=Group , y=reorder(Legend_Taxa,Mean_Abundance), size = Mean_Abundance)) +
        geom_point(alpha=0.5) +
        scale_size(range = c(.1, 24), name="TEST")
```